# How can I use std::result_of to return the function type instead of void

Tags: c++11, templates, std, auto, result-of

I am trying to get the return type of a function that I bind in. In this instance I was expecting to see the return type of `GetFactorialResult` (int).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace
{
    const int testNumber = 10;
    int GetFactorialResult(int number)
    {
        if (number > 1)
        {
            return number * GetFactorialResult(number - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    template <typename Func, typename... Args>
    void Submit(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto boundTask = std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        using ResultType = typename std::result_of<decltype(boundTask)()>::type;

        char const * name = typeid( ResultType ).name();
        std::cout << boost::core::demangle( name ) << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    Submit([](int number)
        {
        GetFactorialResult(number);
        }, number);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
void
0
```

When I print the type of `boundTask`, I see what I expect:

> std::_Bind<\main::{lambda(int)#1} (int)>    (the backslash doesnt
>   exist, but couldnt figure out how to display it without it).

I assume I am getting void because of I'm doing `decltype(boundTask)()`, but if I remove the parenthesis, it fails to compile.

I only have access to c++11 features.

Comment: Your lambda does not have a return statement, so the return type ends up being `void`. Add a return statement and it should behave as expected. `Submit([](int number) { return GetFactorialResult(number); }, number);`
Some languages like Rust and Swift will implicitly return the result of the last or only statement -- C++ requires an explicit `return`.

Comment: Doh! That fixed everything, cant believe I missed that. Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this and respond!